# Libgdx Parallax shader

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader, parallax

I'm trying to make a shader-backed parallax effect using shader code listed [here](http://notnowlewis.com/blog/2013/12/18/parallax-background-glsl-shaders/). But what I get is only a white screen.

Also the forum post [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21675#p89506) says that "code doesn't use a SpriteBatch, it renders the Mesh directly with the texture parameters set up in the shader".

I've never seen ShaderProgram to be used without setting it to a batch before, so might be I'm missing something very fundamental here.

```
 public class Parallax {

        private final ShaderProgram parallaxShader;
        private final FullscreenQuad fullscreenQuad;
        private final Array<Texture> backgrounds;

        public Parallax(final String parallaxTexturesSubfolderName) {
            parallaxShader = initShader();
            fullscreenQuad = new FullscreenQuad();

            backgrounds = populateBackgrounds(parallaxTexturesSubfolderName);
        }

        private Array<Texture> populateBackgrounds(String parallaxTexturesSubfolderName) {
            final Array<Texture> textures = new Array<Texture>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                final Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("parallax/" + parallaxTexturesSubfolderName + "/" + "img" + i + ".png"));
                  texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat, Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat);
                textures.add(texture);
            }
            return textures;
        }


        private ShaderProgram initShader() {
            ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
            final String vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/parallax-vert.glsl").readString();
            final String fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/parallax-frag.glsl").readString();

            final ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
            if (!shader.isCompiled()) {
                Gdx.app.log("ShaderTest", shader.getLog());
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
            return shader;
        }


        public void render(final Camera camera, final SpriteBatch batch) {
    //        batch.setShader(parallaxShader); //tried with batch also - doesn't seems to work
    //        batch.begin(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.size; i++) {
                backgrounds.get(i).bind(i);
            }

            float travelDistance = camera.position.x / 800f / 15f;
            parallaxShader.begin();
//            parallaxShader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined); 
            parallaxShader.setUniformf("travelDistance", travelDistance);
            parallaxShader.setUniformi("u_texture0", 0);
            parallaxShader.setUniformi("u_texture1", 1);
            parallaxShader.setUniformi("u_texture2", 2);
            parallaxShader.setUniformi("u_texture3", 3);
            fullscreenQuad.render(parallaxShader);
            parallaxShader.end();
    //        batch.setShader(null);
    //        batch.end();
        }

        public void dispose() {
          ...
        }
    }
```

FullscreenQuad is listed [here](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/blob/master/postprocessing/src/main/java/com/bitfire/postprocessing/utils/FullscreenQuad.java). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That FullscreenQuad class uses `a_texCoord0` for the UVs name, but the shader from the tutorial uses `a_texCoords`. These names need to match.

To avoid difficult-to-debug problems like this, I would recommend not turning off `ShaderProgram.pedantic` while doing development builds. But do use it for releases to avoid hard crashes.

**Unrelated to your issue:** 
The tutorial's last three lines in the fragment shader put a lot of hope in non-guaranteed compile-time optimizations. GLSL already has an optimized linear interpolation function. It *might* also be faster to only calculate RGB, since alpha will be unused in the end. The last lines should be changed to something like this.

```
gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, texel1.rgb, texel1.a);
gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, texel2.rgb, texel2.a);
gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, texel3.rgb, texel3.a);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That did the trick! However, now all other textures are rendered white. Neither batch.setShader(null) nor batch.end() helps. Can you please suggest how to un-apply shader?

Comment: If you've already called batch.begin before parallax.render, you need to call batch.end before you start doing anything with the shader or rendering with FuScreenQuad.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Finally went with RenderingContext. Not sure about performance overhead (because of RenderingContext usage), but I have a plan to look later why  batch.end didn't work for that case.